# Replying multiple messages from a nested chain called by gateway

Tags: java, spring-integration

Based on my previous problem I have created the following flow:

```
<int:channel id="output.buffer.channel"/>

<int:chain id="pollingBaseChain" input-channel="pollingInput">
    <int:poller ref="pollingInputPoller"/>
    <int:gateway id="inputChainGateway" request-channel="input.buffer.channel" reply-channel="output.buffer.channel"/>
    <int:service-activator id="outboundRoutingService" ref="outboundMessageRouterService" method="forwardMessage"/>
</int:chain>

<int:chain id="input.chain" input-channel="input.buffer.channel" output-channel="output.buffer.channel">
    <int:poller ref="inputPoller"/>
    <!-- Various service activators/transfomers -->
    <int:splitter id="messageSplitter" ref="messageSplitterSequence" apply-sequence="false"/>
    <int:transformer id="outboundEntries" ref="routingService" method="prepareOutboundEntries"/>
</int:chain>
```

Inside the service-activator `outboundRoutingService` very little code happens:

```
public void forwardMessage(Message message, @Header(value = "nextChannel", required = false) MessageChannel channel) {
    logger.info("Received message for routing. Channel is: {}, message is: {}", channel, message);

    if(channel != null) {
        channel.send(message);
    }
}
```

Now I send 25 messages into the flow, they get picked up by the `pollingBaseChain`, forwarded to the `input.chain` via the `gateway` and processed there. Inside that chain they get split into 5 messages and 125 messages are leaving the `input.chain`. The `forwardMessage` from the `outboundRoutingService` logs 25 messages. I believe this is because the gateway attempts to match messages by their ID, so only the 25 original messages are picked up (and what happens to the others?) and forwarded.

This is my first problem, is there a way, that all messages that are emitted by the `input.chain` continue flowing in the `pollingBaseChain` and get forwarded to the `outboundRoutingService` service-activator?

My second problem is, that while 25 messages arrived in `forwardMessage` with a non-null `channel` only 1 single message was picked up by the channel they have been sent to inside the `forwardMessage`. This channel is a `QueueChannel` with much more than 25 messages queue size. Where could those messages get lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gateway request-reply is based on the `TemporaryReplyChannel` for the `replyChannel` header, which is essentially is a `private final CountDownLatch replyLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);`. So, it is really one reply for one request. The gateway has no knowledge about downstream and its possibility to produce many massages.

To honor "one for one" contract you need to consider to *aggregate* all those messages before sending to the reply channel.

See more info about aggregator in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator

You may consider to *split* the result back to the bunch of messages after gateway though.